# NavigationDrawer in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigation-drawer

I building an app using `Xamarin.iOS`.

I have to list a lot of categories in something similar like `NavigationDrawer` in `Android`. When I have up to 4-5 options(categories) I have used `ActionSheet` dialogs, but now I have up to 15 categories.

Any suggestion on how I can implement, are any third part libraries or any helping tutorial. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you had a look at these components:

- [Side Bar Navigation componenet](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sidebarnavigation) and the [source](https://github.com/jdehlin/Xamarin-Sidebar)
- [Flyoutnavigation](https://components.xamarin.com/view/flyoutnavigation)
- [JaSidePanels](https://components.xamarin.com/view/jasidepanels)
- [RESideMenu.Xamarin.iOS](https://github.com/maxname/RESideMenu.Xamarin.iOS)
- [SlidingMenu_Xamarin.iOS](https://github.com/suchithm/SlidingMenu_Xamarin.iOS) with blog post [here](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2015/09/sliding-menu-in-xamarinios-using.html)

And check the "Getting Started" section on each of these to see how to set it up.

Any issues let me know.

Comment: I have been working with Side Bar Navigation, but there are some problem. I need the SideBar in the inner screen of the app. The app has some sections and in one of them I need the SideBar. I have used NavigationController since the first screen of the app so I can't use the library in the way its described in the document. Its seems that I can't access the NavigationBar from the ContetController or SideBarMenu Controller.

Comment: Im not too sure what you mean? Do you want a Side Bar navigation only in one part of the app and not through out ?

Comment: I need to use the SideBar component. The situation is: I have a HomePage with a bunch of categories. When I click in one of the categories  I navigate to a second screen. Now in this second screen I want to implement the SideBar Navigation. Is there an example for this.